# Game Of Life Program C Sharp

Tags: c#, conways-game-of-life

So I'm trying to Program Conway's Game of Life but I don't know how to approach the part where it checks around them? Any ideas? I've labeled the area "SIMULATION CODE HERE"

I don't need you to do it for me, I just need a tip on how to approach this part of the process as I have no clue on how to check the area around the array, to see how many alive dots exist, etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Gameoflife
{
class Program
{
    static int[,] currentgeneration = new int[Console.LargestWindowHeight + 1, Console.LargestWindowWidth + 1];
    static int[,] nextgeneration = new int[Console.LargestWindowHeight + 1, Console.LargestWindowWidth + 1];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleColor cellcolour = ConsoleColor.Green;
        ConsoleColor backgroundcolour = ConsoleColor.Black;

        Introduction();

        Console.Title = "GAME OF LIFE SIMULATION";
        int worldwidth = Console.LargestWindowWidth;
        int worldheight = Console.LargestWindowHeight;
        Console.SetWindowSize(worldwidth, worldheight);
        Console.SetWindowPosition(0, 0);




        setupworld(worldwidth, worldheight, cellcolour, backgroundcolour);




        int generation = 0;
        DrawWorld(worldwidth, worldheight, cellcolour, backgroundcolour, generation);

        // SIMULATION CODE HERE!



        generation++;
        for (int row = 1; row < worldheight; row++)
        {

            for (int col = 1; col < worldwidth; col++)

            {

                currentgeneration[row, col] = nextgeneration[row, col];

            }

        }
        DrawWorld(worldwidth, worldheight, cellcolour, backgroundcolour, generation);

    }






    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    static void Introduction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CONWAY'S GAME OF LIFE");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("To set up your starting world use the following keys..");
        Console.WriteLine("Arrow keys  - move around the screen");
        Console.WriteLine("Space Bar   - places a cell in that location");
        Console.WriteLine("Escape key  - To end setup");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
    }




    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    static void setupworld(int worldwidth, int worldheight, ConsoleColor cellcolour, ConsoleColor backgroundcolour)
    {
        Boolean setupcomplete = false;
        int cursorx = 1; 
        int cursory = 1; 
        Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorx, cursory);
        while (!setupcomplete)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey();
                switch (cki.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        if (cursory > 1)
                        {
                            cursory = cursory - 1;
                        }
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        if (cursory < Console.LargestWindowHeight - 1)
                        {
                            cursory = cursory + 1;
                        }
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                        if (cursorx > 1)
                        {
                            cursorx = cursorx - 1;
                        }
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                        if (cursorx < Console.LargestWindowWidth - 1)
                        {
                            cursorx = cursorx + 1;
                        }
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.Spacebar:
                        currentgeneration[cursory, cursorx] = 1;
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                        setupcomplete = true;
                        break;
                }
                DrawWorld(worldwidth, worldheight, cellcolour, backgroundcolour, 0);
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorx, cursory);
            }

        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 0);
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Write("Press Any key to now start the simulation");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    static void DrawWorld(int worldwidth, int worldheight, ConsoleColor cellcolour, ConsoleColor backgroundcolour, int generation)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write("Generation: {0}", generation);
        for (int r = 0; r < worldheight; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < worldwidth; c++)
            {
                if (currentgeneration[r, c] == 1)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(c, r);
                    Console.BackgroundColor = cellcolour;
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    Console.BackgroundColor = backgroundcolour;
                }
            }  
        } 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: currentgeneration[r-1, c] is above it, currentgeneration[r, c-1] is left to it but check that r-1 and c-1 are not negative.

Comment: Typically a Conway workd wraps around, so you need to calulate the neighbouring indices by doing just that.: instead of `i+1` or `i-1` you need `(i+1)%worldwidth` and `(i-1+worldwidth) % worldwidth)`..

Answer (score 1):

Start by writing down the rules in plain English:

- Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies, as if by underpopulation.
- Any live cell with two or three live neighbors lives on to the next generation.
- Any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies, as if by overpopulation.
- Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

Your job is now to convert these plain English statements into code. For the code to work, you must know what inputs it needs. So we need to go over the statements to see what it computes over:

- Any **live** cell with fewer than two **live neighbors** dies, as if by underpopulation.
- Any **live** cell with two or three **live neighbors** lives on to the next generation.
- Any **live** cell with more than three **live neighbors** dies, as if by overpopulation.
- Any **dead** cell with exactly three **live neighbors** becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

Based on this analysis, we now know that our code will need two inputs:

1. It needs to know whether the current cell is alive
2. It needs to know how many neighboring cells are alive.

To compute whether the cell is alive, I assume you'd look at `currentgeneration[r,c]`.

To compute how many neighboring cells are alive, you'd look at all of the following:

```
currentgeneration[r-1,c-1] 
currentgeneration[r-1,c  ] 
currentgeneration[r-1,c+1] 
currentgeneration[r  ,c-1] 
currentgeneration[r  ,c  ] 
currentgeneration[r  ,c+1] 
currentgeneration[r+1,c-1] 
currentgeneration[r+1,c  ] 
currentgeneration[r+1,c+1]
```

So your code would need to inspect all of those elements and count the ones that are active.

You can then write a function that takes the two inputs and determines if a cell is alive:

```
bool IsAlive(bool wasAlive, int count)
{
    if (wasAlive && count<2) return false;                 // Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies, as if by underpopulation.
    if (wasAlive && (count==2 || count == 3)) return true; // Any live cell with two or three live neighbors lives on to the next generation.
    if (wasAlive && count>=3) return false;                // Any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies, as if by overpopulation.
    if (!wasAlive && count == 3) return true;              // Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.
}
```

And now we can write a method that retrieves the data to pass to the function:

```
bool IsAlive(int r, int c)
{
    var count = currentgeneration[r-1,c-1] 
              + currentgeneration[r-1,c  ] 
              + currentgeneration[r-1,c+1] 
              + currentgeneration[r  ,c-1] 
              + currentgeneration[r  ,c  ] 
              + currentgeneration[r  ,c+1] 
              + currentgeneration[r+1,c-1] 
              + currentgeneration[r+1,c  ] 
              + currentgeneration[r+1,c+1];
    var isAlive = ( currentgeneration[r,c] == 1);
    return IsAlive(isAlive, count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add 2 more arrays, one tracking which cells are alive (`bool`) and another one tracking how many neighbours a cell has (`int`).

At each update, cycle through the alive cells and add increment the neighbour array at the positions around it. Once you are done, simply kill, spawn or leave cells alone depending on the number of neighbours at that position.

Here's an exemple of a that program in JavaScript:

**Add Neighbour**

```
// Iterate through the alive array
// If the cell at that position is alive...
if (alive[x][y] == true)
{
    for (X = -1; X <= 1; X++)
    {
        for (Y = -1; Y <= 1; Y++)
        {
            // Get the coordinates of the positions around it
            dx = x + X;
            dy = y + Y;

            // If the coordinates are valid
            if (dx >= 0 && dy >= 0 && dx < ROW && dy < COLUMN)
            {
                // Increment the neighbour array
                neighbours[dx][dy] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update the alive array**

```
// If the cell is alive...
if (alive[x][y] == true)
{
    // Remove the bias (the UpdateNeighbour function adds neighbour in a 3x3 area, not only the neighbours.)
    numNeighbours -= 1;

    // If it has less than 2 neighbours...
    if (numNeighbours < 2)
    {
        // It dies
        alive[i][y] = false;
    }
    // If it has 2 or 3 neighbours...
    else if(numNeighbours < 4)
    {
        // It survives
        alive[i][y] = true;
    }
    // If it has more than 4 neighbours...
    else if (numNeighbours >= 4)
    {
        // It dies
        alive[i][y] = false;
    }
}

// If the cell isn't alive but has exactly 3 neighbours...
else if (alive[x][y] == false && numNeighbours == 3)
{
    // Spawn new cell
    alive[x][y] = true;
}
```